# Start HTML rows as collapsed by default

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have implemented my version of this example (using Vapor Swift & Leaf) and it works fine: [Simple example of collapsible rows in HTML/CSS/JS](https://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/gaGBZz)

However, I want all of the collapsible rows to start off hidden by default. I don't know JS very well but I don't think modifying this would help:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="toggle"]').change(function(){
        $(this).parents().next('.hide').toggle();
    });
});
```

Do I need to make a different JS script and if so how will it find the correct rows to hide (and how to hide them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) library, you can use a jQuery selector to select the elements you want to hide, and hide them on document load:

It looks like the rows that you want to toggle between hidden/shown all have the `.hide` class. So you can use that as the selector:

```
$('.hide').toggle();  // hide rows initially
```

Run the snippet below to see how this works. Initially, the rows are hidden. If you click "Accounting" or "Management" the rows will expand.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hide').toggle();  // hide rows initially
  $('[data-toggle="toggle"]').change(function() {
    $(this).parents().next('.hide').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 750px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

th {
  background: #3498db;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.labels tr td {
  background-color: #2cc16a;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.label tr td label {
  display: block;
}

[data-toggle="toggle"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Regian</th>
      <th>Q1 2010</th>
      <th>Q2 2010</th>
      <th>Q3 2010</th>
      <th>Q4 2010</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tbody class="labels">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
          <label for="accounting">Accounting</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="accounting" id="accounting" data-toggle="toggle">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="hide">
      <tr>
        <td>Australia</td>
        <td>$7,685.00</td>
        <td>$3,544.00</td>
        <td>$5,834.00</td>
        <td>$10,583.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Central America</td>
        <td>$7,685.00</td>
        <td>$3,544.00</td>
        <td>$5,834.00</td>
        <td>$10,583.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="labels">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
          <label for="management">Management</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="management" id="management" data-toggle="toggle">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="hide">
      <tr>
        <td>Australia</td>
        <td>$7,685.00</td>
        <td>$3,544.00</td>
        <td>$5,834.00</td>
        <td>$10,583.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Central America</td>
        <td>$7,685.00</td>
        <td>$3,544.00</td>
        <td>$5,834.00</td>
        <td>$10,583.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Europe</td>
        <td>$7,685.00</td>
        <td>$3,544.00</td>
        <td>$5,834.00</td>
        <td>$10,583.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Middle East</td>
        <td>$7,685.00</td>
        <td>$3,544.00</td>
        <td>$5,834.00</td>
        <td>$10,583.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. That does indeed hide them. But they no longer unhide when you click on the relevant labels (i.e., toggle is now broken). Is there any reason to think we broke the other original toggle function?

Comment: Nevermind, I get it. I was supposed to delete the original function. Works!